# My Network UserID keeps getting locked out, but it isn't me. Where is my ID embedded?

Tags: windows

My network user id keeps getting locked out, but I'm not doing it.  I'm positive no one is using it besides me, but it is embedded in various places, for example I have a local IIS instance that is using it.  However, my ID was locked over the weekend & I wasn't working.  I'm assuming that my id is embedded somewhere else with an old password.  How can I find out where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scour the Windows Security event logs on the machines where you may have set up scheduled tasks or services to run as you.  Or if it's consistently happening, power down a machine and see if you still get locked out, if you do it's not that powered off machine, use the process of elimination that way (if possible).

Comment: Thanks, I checked the event log.  It looks like it was Windwos Backup.